# Force closed xamarin android app Who used the SQLite-net crud operation

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem in SQLite-net in xamarin
when releasing my project and install the apk on a device when using SQLite (crud operation) app is force closed! 
If there is no problem with the cable to connect the device to the computer and use it to debug the program!
Do you know what the cause of this problem? 
Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished the result!!!!!!!  :o

The big reason for not getting your permission nowadays is because your project has a targetSdkVersion of 23 or higher, and the permission that you are requesting is "dangerous". In Android 6.0, this includes:
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ADD_VOICEMAIL
BODY_SENSORS
CALL_PHONE
CAMERA
...

For these permissions, not only does your targetSdkVersion 23+ app need to have the element(s), but you also have to ask for those permissions at runtime from the user on Android 6.0+ devices, using methods like checkSelfPermission() and requestPermissions().

As a temporary workaround, drop your targetSdkVersion below 23.

However, eventually, you will have some reason to want your targetSdkVersion to be 23 or higher. At that time, you will need to adjust your app to use the new runtime permission system.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you violating something (my bet is permissions)  With the device connected to the computer run the release project while watching the logcat in the Android Device monitor it should give you the answer you need or at least a stack trace as to why its crashing... Without a stack trace or further info this is the best I can offer you.

Answer (score 0):

@snowCrabs tank you for your answer
i use android 7(api24) already install sdk

[image]

Testing and implementing on the device and connecting with cable (Device is Samsung tablet galexy tab A6(android 7.0)